# BaseController input param Object results in Multiple actions were found that match the request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I've got this intresting situation where I have a baseController for webApi and have tracked the issue down to this. If I have a base controller that has an input parameter type Object it will end up with http 500 Multiple actions where found...

And this is in a default empty mvc 4.0 project for vs 2012 using IISExpress

```
public class BaseSecureApi : ApiController
{
    public string Wtf(object ohMyGodThisIsSilly)
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

And the controller

```
public class Default1Controller : BaseSecureApi
{
    // GET api/default1
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // POST api/default1
    [HttpPost]
    public string Post([FromBody]string value)
    {

        return "Postmyvalue:" + value;
    }
}
```

And a route

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Now why is the routing going haywire. 
IRL the base class returns a httpResponse based on who is logged on and if the result should be encrypted or not.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce using the posted code, but I don't get the result you get. I get the same result if I rename the Wtf method to GetWtf though.

Comment: Which environment are you using @OlavNybø? Just checked my test project and it crashes.

Comment: I get the same results as you do when posting, I initially only tried get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [routing-and-action-selection article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection) on the ASP.NET site:

> HTTP Methods. The framework only chooses actions that match the HTTP method of the request, determined as follows:
>
> 1. You can specify the HTTP method with an attribute: AcceptVerbs, HttpDelete, HttpGet, HttpHead, HttpOptions, HttpPatch, HttpPost, or HttpPut.
> 2. Otherwise, if the name of the controller method starts with "Get", "Post", "Put", "Delete", "Head", "Options", or "Patch", then by convention the action supports that HTTP method.
> 3. If none of the above, the method supports POST.

This means that the Wtf method will support POST because it is a public method, with no attributes and it does not start with any of the conventional words.

If you make the Wtf method protected and it will not be called by the Web api, you can still call it from the methods of your derived classes where you need to.

Comment: Ahhh I Read the article but missed point nr3... If all else failed it will support POST. Someone should get severly thrashed across the bum for that else/default statement. And for others this might help. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/04/04/debugging-asp-net-web-api-with-route-debugger.aspx . 
Which is a route debugger.